# PostgreSQL query: write a query to return the maximum of each group of consecutive numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Given a set of numbers like "1,2,3,6,7,8,11,12,15,18,19,20", write a query to return the maximum of each group of consecutive numbers.

need to first find which numbers should be in a group, and then find the max in each group.

```
create table tt (c1 numeric);
insert into tt values
(1),(2),(3),(6),(7),(8),(11),(12),(15),(18),(19),(20);
```

So the answer would be 3, 8, 12, 15, 20

Comment: Which result do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot close this question as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606818/postgresql-given-1-2-3-6-7-8-11-12-15-18-19-20-a-query-to-return-the-maximum/62609483#62609483), but I can copy my answer here:
Assuming you want 3, 8, 12, 15, and 20, you would use lead():

```
select c1
from (select t.*, lead(c1) over (order by c1) as next_c1
      from table1 t
     ) t
where next_c1 is distinct from c1 + 1;
```

This uses the observation that you can find the end number just by comparing the "next number" to the current value plus 1.

If you want these in a string:

```
select string_agg(c1::text, ',' order by c1)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7c03c024d94715b1b8ac502d035add06) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

I would rephrase your question as: get numbers whose next value is not in sequence. If so, you can just use window functions:

```
select *
from (select c1, lead(c1) over(order by c1) lead_c1 from tt) t
where lead_c1 <> c1 + 1
```

For your sample data, **[this produces](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e647a2d178cee6fbea7e5a9a81efb53d)**:

```
c1 | lead_c1
-: | ------:
 3 |       6
 8 |      11
12 |      15
15 |      18
```

If you want to also capture the very last record (which, obviously, has no follower), you can change the `where` clause to:

```
where lead_c1 <> c1 + 1 or lead_c1 is null
```